# Android push notification doesn't open app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently building an android app with some FCM usage. Unfortunately I am not able to put this all together. I have connected firebase to my app successfully, .json file (generated by my API provider) is also well placed. If app is in foreground, onMessagReceived is called properly. Push notifications are also received properly, but click event on notification (while in background) does absolutely nothing. Notification disappears without opening launch activity. If I switch .json file to one that was generated by me with sample FCM app, click on notifications works in a desired way. I have no idea what is going on.

Below I present part of my AndroidManifest.xml with launcher activity/fcm services and .json file generated by my api provider (some data were changed, but particular values are equal):

```
<application
    android:name=".xyz"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/xyz"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.xyz.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.xyz.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="xyz.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/api,xyz"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="xyz.pl"
                android:pathPrefix="/api,xzz"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    ...

    <service android:name=".services.xyzFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".services.xyzFirebaseInstanceService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    </activity>

</application>
```

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "123456789123",
    "firebase_url": "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "xxx",
    "storage_bucket": "xxx.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:123456789123:android:a12a3456789012e1",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.mycompany.myapp"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "123456789123-zzz.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "current_key"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I also include sample fcm message generated by my api provider.

```
    [2017-11-02 12:10:06] https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
HEADERS: [
    "Authorization:key=my_auth_key"
]
DATA: {
    "notification": {
        "icon": "https://www.myavatar.com/avatar.png",
        "title": "Message title",
        "body": "aaa",
        "click_action": "https://www.app.com/notifications,open?_id=678696787lkju82"
    },
    "data": {
        "date_create": "2017-11-02 12:10:04",
        "sender_type": "user",
        "sender_app_id": "2",
        "sender_app_display": "MyApp",
        "sender_user_id": "43",
        "sender_display": "WK",
        "type": "message"
    },
    "to": "fYqHDJEVUUM:APAasdasdasdHS_GOsen-kkjghkasjhd898098klj-8797hoijo8"
}
RESPONSE: {
    "multicast_id": 556579726904--2753,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1880938748%hkk4bjl2k1"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've found the problem. The "click_action" parameter was causing the problem, my api provider set url address as value of this parameter to help himself on the web side and that was it ;) Big thanks to @Barns52 for giuding me to solution.

Comment: Please read the Firebase documentation on different message payloads. FCM offers two different payloads. Each payload type is handled differently when the app is in background.

Comment: I wouldn't create new topic if I not read documentation before. It says "Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default."  My api provider sends me notification messages, and click on notification on tray does nothing.

Comment: In that case, you need to post the code you are using to generate the message and the code you are using to receive the message. Just posting the `AndroidManifest` will get us basically nowhere in diagnosing the mistake you made.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Basically I dont have any advanced implementation of receiving messages, just a class extending FirebaseMessagingService with empty onMessageReceived() method. I thaught that android handles click on push notifications with type notification by itself. I dont have any both or data types yet, so I really don't see any field for making mistake on android side. Is it possible that api-side error causes sending not able to open notifications?

Comment: At the very least I need to see how the message is created. You wrote in you post " .json file (generated by my API provider)" I need to see at least the content of the json file.

Comment: ok, I've added content of .json file.

Comment: I need the message json. It will look like this::    {
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I finally received sample fcm message json from my api provider, so I pasted it at the end of post.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. You(!) found the solution that will help you get your solution moving forward. Enjoy programming!

Comment: After trying every solution on stackoverflow only this one worked for me. Please post your solution as an answer for others. Thanks.

Comment: @J.F3AR can you please tell me did you made the web API remove the URL in click_action ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added this at the end of a post, but it probably should be here:

I've found the problem. The "click_action" parameter was causing the problem, my api provider set url address as value of this parameter to help himself on the web side and that was it ;) Big thanks to @Barns52 for giuding me to solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicit make a call to an activity.